# Python to log in Windows automatically with task scheduler

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I created a python script to automate a task.
I would like to run it every day on a hourly basis and for this I created a task in Windows Task Scheduler.

Is there a way to write a script to log in Windows automatically when my account is logged out? My script fails if the Windows user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to approach this.  It's normal and expected that your computer will not always be logged in.  You should not try to change that, as it would be very insecure.

The right thing to do is figure out why your script will not run when the system is not logged in.  When setting your task up, you can set user credentials it should use when starting.  Make sure your program is not making any incorrect assumptions about accessibility or security when it runs.

Comment: The automation uses OCR technology that is why it needs to be logged in otherwise it is not able to scrape the screen.

Comment: What is it scraping?  A web page, or a captured image?  There likely is an alternative approach.

Comment: It is a captured image from an application.